# How to use math mode on tex.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to ask a question that involves some latex characters in math mode

I type in `$\mathcal{Z}$`, which works on math.stackexchange and various other SE sites, and nothing appears

Can someone provide an instruction as to how you would type in math mode on tex.stackechange?

Comment: We are interested in the code, so MathJax is disabled.

Comment: type the tex code in a code section `{}` in the editor, and/or show the typeset output by making an image of the result as typeset by TeX (not mathjax) and posting the image.